# Unique ID that gets a date in specific format?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have code that will generate a random unique id.. but is there a way I can edit this code so that it grabs a date in a specific way like yyyy-mm-dd-0001. the last 4 digits I want it to add 1 each time the generateid button is clicked. so it will change to 0002. Here is the current code I have. Is there a function that can grab the date automatically?

```
  var counter = 0000;
    function Counter() {
if((document.getElementById("generateid").clicked == true)
{
Counter++
return counter;
}
    }




    function Month() {
        var m = new Date();
        var mm = m.getMonth() + 1;
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm;
            return mm;
        } 


    }
    function Year() {
        var y = new Date();
        var yy = y.getFullYear();
        return yy;
    }
    function Day() {
        var d = new Date();
        var dd = d.getDate();
        return dd;
    }
//generate id
    function guidGenerator() {
        var theID = (Year() + "-" + Month() + "-" + Day() + "-" + Counter);
        return theID;
    }

    function generateID() {

        var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("generateidtxt");
        TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + guidGenerator();
        document.getElementById("generateid").disabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at JavaScript `Date` Object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp. You will also need to call your function from an object of your own if you want persitant sequence of IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following object:

```
var idGenerator  = {
    seq: 0,
    generateId: function () {
       this.seq++;
       return (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10) + '-' + ('000' + this.seq).substr(-4)
    }
}
```

after declaration like this, try

```
function generateID() {
   var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("generateidtxt");
   TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + idGenerator.generateId();
   document.getElementById("generateid").disabled=true;    
}
```

Comment: I will show the new code that I have, Thanks. I just require the counter part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a way to keep track of how many times an ID is generated by all your site visitors using javascript alone then, no it is not possible without tying in some back end to keep track.  However, the following code will do what you ask per visitor.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuFEZ/9/)

```
var ttlIds = 0;

function guidGenerator() {
    var S4 = function () {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
    return (S4() + S4() + S4());

}

function generateID() {

    var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("generateidtxt");
    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + guidGenerator().toString().toUpperCase();
    //document.getElementById("generateid").disabled=true; 

    ttlIds++;
    if(ttlIds < 10){
        ttlIds_formatted = '000'+ttlIds;
    }else if(ttlIds < 100){
        ttlIds_formatted = '00'+ttlIds;
    }else if(ttlIds < 1000){
        ttlIds_formatted = '0'+ttlIds;    
    }
    d = new Date();
    var funkydate = d.getFullYear() +'-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate() + '-' + ttlIds_formatted;
    document.getElementById("funkydate").value = funkydate;

}
```